# pandas str.contains() gives wrong results?

Tags: python, string, pandas

For example;

```
pd.Series('ASKING CD.').str.contains('AS')
Out[58]: 
0    True
dtype: bool

pd.Series('ASKING CD.').str.contains('ASG')
Out[59]: 
0    False
dtype: bool

pd.Series('ASKING CD.').str.contains('SK.')
Out[60]: 
0    True
dtype: bool
```

Why the 3rd output is True? There is no 'SK.' sequence in passed string. **'dot'** character doesn't mean anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regex `.` means match any character. Solutions is escape `.` or add parameter `regex=False`:

```
print(pd.Series('ASKING CD.').str.contains(r'SK\.'))
0    False
dtype: bool

print(pd.Series('ASKING CD.').str.contains('SK.', regex=False))
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try the 'SK\.' in first place but didn't get the idea. And now I noticed that default parameter  was  ** regex=True **. It works now. Thx.